# Use the EucDistance function of ArcPy in PyCharm

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, distance, pycharm, euclidean

I failed to calculate the Euclidean distance with the EucDistance function in the PyCharm. The codes are as follows.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
env.workspace = "D:/Study/Reference/ecological integrity/regions"
outEucDistance = EucDistance("Highways1.tif", "", 30, "")
outEucDistance.save("D:/Study/Reference/ecological integrity/ED.tif")
```

Now, I received the following warning message

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:/Software/11.py", line 9, in 
> outEucDistance = EucDistance("Highways1.tif", "", 30,"")
> File "d:\Program Files\ArcGIS 10.4\Desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 968, in EucDistance
> out_direction_raster)
> File "d:\Program Files\ArcGIS 10.4\Desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper
> result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
> File "d:\Program Files\ArcGIS 10.4\Desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 962, in Wrapper
> out_direction_raster)
> File "d:\Program Files\ArcGIS 10.4\Desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line 506, in 
> return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
> arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 010429: GRID IO 中存在错误: GetOpenTileChannel: Could not create tile. name: d:\study\reference\ecological integrity\regions\xx0025560000, adepth: 32, type: 1, iomode: 1, version: 3, compression: 0, eval case: 1 。
> ERROR 010296: 写入栅格 d:\study\reference\ecological integrity\regions\xx0025560000 时出错。 Distance mapping is failed
> ERROR 010067: 执行格网表达式时出错。
> 执行(EucDistance)失败。

The data is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QiS6Dz5bXkiA4TfTeHqLYnyR2AM8zOSK/view?usp=drive_link).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your code does not match the error. Are you actually setting `env.workspace = "D:/study/reference/ecological integrity/regions"`...? A [search of the error](https://www.google.com/search?q=ERROR+010429%3A+GRID+IO+GetOpenTileChannel%3A+Could+not+create+tile) reveals the [answer](https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/problem-unable-to-create-a-grid-format-raster-in-a-loca-000023763)

Comment: Thank you！I just edited the codes to match the warnings. This error is due to the spaces in my name of directory (i.e., ecological integrity). If it is named as "ecological_integrity", this error will be addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code is

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
env.workspace = "D:/Study/Reference/ecological_integrity/regions"
outEucDistance = EucDistance("Highways1.tif", "", 30, "")
outEucDistance.save("D:/Study/Reference/ecological_integrity/ED.tif")
```

The spaces in the name of directory are not permitted. Please refer to [this](https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/problem-unable-to-create-a-grid-format-raster-in-a-loca-000023763).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get this to work without having to rename your folders is as follows:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
env.workspace = r"D:/Study/Reference/ecological integrity/regions"
outEucDistance = EucDistance("Highways1.tif", "", 30, "")
outEucDistance.save(r"D:/Study/Reference/ecological integrity/ED.tif")
```

The r prefix will convert the path text to a raw string.

Comment: That won't work as the path will still have a space in it. And the raw string won't do anything as the variable doesn't contain any backslash characters i.e. \.   https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-raw-strings/